# Cardinality of a discrete set, in a separable space.

Tags: general-topology

Given a separable space $X$, if $A$ is discrete subspace of $X$, then $|A|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Some ideas?. It's similar to "jone's lemma", but without $A$ being closed. Whit what addiotional conditions we can assure the statement becomes true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for $T_3$ spaces.

An open set $O$ is regular open iff $O = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{O})$.

Facts (not very hard):

1. In a $T_3$space, the regular open sets form a base for the topology.
2. If $D \subset X$ is dense, and $O$ is open, $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{D \cap O}) = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{O})$.

Fact 2 implies that the map that sends $A \subset D$ to $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{A})$ has all regular open sets in its image, so that there are at most $2^{|D|}$ many regular open sets in $X$.

Now, if $A$ is discrete, then for every $a \in A$ we can pick a regular open $O_a$ such that $O_a \cap A = \{a\}$, in a $T_3$ space, by fact 1 and the definition of being discrete. Then $a \rightarrow O_a$ is injective from $A$ into the regular open sets, and so combining the above, $|A| \le 2^{|D|}$, and so for a separable space you have what you want.

(This is all inspired by the fact 2.3 from Cardinal Invariants in Topology (1971) [a goto reference for these kinds of questions!] that $w(X) \le \pi(X)^{c(X)} \le 2^{d(X)}$ for $T_3$ spaces). Added: found this [paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ25_01%2FS0004972700005074a.pdf&code=d1c3f21ad067a68f00828a47df480146) with the exact result I stated here, plus Asaf's counterexample as well.

Take $X$ is the set $\omega$ of natural numbers, together with the set of all free ultrafilters on $\omega$, of which there are $2^{2^{\omega}}$. All points of $\omega$ are isolated, and a neighbourhood of an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ is of the form $A \cup \{\mathcal{F}\}$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Then the ultrafilters form a discrete set and $\omega$ is dense. Moreover, the result is a Hausdorff space, which shows we cannot really weaken $T_3$ very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite true without additional assumptions.

Take an arbitrarily large set $X$, and pick a point $x_0\in X$. Define the topology so a set is open if and only if it is empty or $x_0$ is in the set.

Then this topology is separable, since $\{x_0\}$ is a countable dense subset; but at the same time $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ is discrete, since any point $x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$ is open in the relative topology, as witnessed by $\{x,x_0\}$ being open in $X$.

Comment: This is a theorem if we assume $X$ is T$_1$, right?

Comment: @TomCruise No, we need $T_3$, not even $T_2$ is enough. See below.

Comment: @Henno: Depends on the order of the answers, it might be above!